# Basic understanding of Firebase security

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Fundamentally, if my client side javascript is going to be modifying my Firebase data remotely, couldn't anyone come along and examine that code and start modifying the same Firebase data at will?

I know they can't modify areas of the data that are off limits to various users or situations, but if for example a user has the ability to create blog posts, couldn't they log in, examine/manipulate the local copy of my javascript, and send Firebase requests to create millions of blog posts?

Basically, any secret that i make known to my client side javascript in order to empower it to change Firebase data is also known to any client side user, right?

Comment: Yes. Anything that you put in your code, is likely to be discovered by a user. So it is a bad idea to put secrets into your application code. Instead you normally let your users authenticate against a trusted service (such as one of the supported providers for Firebase's login) and build an authorization scheme around that using Firebase's security rules.

Comment: Security rules are [covered here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/). Authentication is [outlined here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html).

Comment: Thanks, I read through those, but as I often find with tech API security literature, they are clear about their implementation details but not very helpful for getting an overview of how the security works.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't particularly unique to Firebase.  If instead of using Firebase you had your own backend server that clients send REST requests to or whatever, a user could just look at the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools and quickly figure out how to manually create blog posts via REST requests.  This sort of thing is really more of an abuse problem than a security problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Anything you put into your source code, is likely to be discovered by a user. So it is a bad idea to put secrets into your application code.

Instead you normally let your users authenticate against a trusted service (such as one of the supported providers for [Firebase's login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html)) and build an authorization scheme around that using [Firebase's security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/).

Comment: This answer, together with Michael Lehenbauer's comment on the original post, help me understand the boundaries of how security works with this sort of API...